# Android: Inserting data to database

Tags: android, database

The data sent is not saved in the database, and I don't know what code I missed to add. The flow of the app is to save the supposedly sent data to the database and the database will display it to the list view in one of the tab. Here's the code for the send button and the populate fields to database:

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
                String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString(); 
                Log.d(phoneNo, message);
                saveState(phoneNo, message);
                boolean split = false;

                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                         "Your message " + "\"" + message + "\"" + " is sent to " +"\""+ phoneNo+"\"", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                Runnable showToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      dialog.cancel();
                      toast.show();
                  }
              };

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)  {
                    showProgress();
                    if (count == 0) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 0);
                      }
                      else if (count == 1) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 15000);
                      }
                      else if (count == 2) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 30000);
                      }
                      else if (count == 3) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 60000);
                      }
                }

                   // sendSMS(phoneNo, message, split); */
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }

     private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId!=null) {
            Cursor message=mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(message);
            editTextRecipient.setText(message.getString(message.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_RECIPIENT)));
            editTextNewMessage.setText(message.getString(message.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE)));
        }
     }

     private void saveState(String phoneNo, String message) {
         Log.i(phoneNo, message);

        if (mRowId==null) {
            mDbHelper.createNote(phoneNo, message);
        }
     }
```

and here's the code of the database:

```
public class MessagesDBAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_RECIPIENT = "recipient";
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "body";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;


     //Database creation sql statement

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, body text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "messages";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public MessagesDBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public MessagesDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long createNote(String phoneNo, String message) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        open();

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_RECIPIENT,
                KEY_MESSAGE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_RECIPIENT, KEY_MESSAGE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String phoneNo, String message) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
        args.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: // The Android's default system path of your application database.
 public String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.minibible.cubix/databases/";

 public static String DB_NAME = "MBC.db";

Comment: You might be missing path to your database. Because you haven't mentioned path to your database in your code. Thanks

Comment: What should I do then? What should I add?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public long insertData(String TableName, String[] ColumnNames,
                String[] Values) {

            String myPath = this.DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            this.dbHandler();

            ContentValues dataObj = new ContentValues();
            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.length; i++) {
                dataObj.put(ColumnNames[i], Values[i]);
            }
            return (this.db.insert(TableName, null, dataObj));

        }



public void dbHandler() {
        String myPath = this.DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (this.db != null) {
            if (this.cursor != null) {

                try {
                    // OPEN
                    this.cursor.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
            this.db.close();
            this.db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } else {
            this.db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }
    }
```